# Private Messaging(User A to User B)

Tags: ios7, chat, message, parse-platform, private

I am trying to create a part of my app which allows users to message one another. The messages will only be one-to-one PM. I'm using Parse as the backend. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to have an associative table ( create it from your Parse.com website account ) that should contains the pointer to the sender User, the pointer to the Receiver User and the message to send. So:

let's call the table class you need as "UsersChat"

`objectId` *(string)* default parse field

`senderUser` *(Pointer:User)* pointer to the user who send the message

`receiverUser` *(Pointer:User)* pointer to the user who will receive the message

`message` *(string)* concrete message to send

`createdAt` *(Date)* default parse field that contains the creation row, so the sent message date/time we can say

`updatedAt` *(Date)* default parse field

`ACL` *(ACL)* default parse field

Comment: Awesome! Do you know any step by step tutorial or maybe a project I can lock at?

Comment: About parse.com you can see how many-to-many relationship works. It exposes the same logic of a common ER (Entity Relationship) model